# Passing around reference of structure is invalidated

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, unordered-map

I am not sure what is causing the error. I have created a workable substitute in the following code that replicates the problem I am facing. The code is self explanatory.

Here are the structure declarations

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    Point(float _x, float _y, float _z)
        : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct Polyline
{
    std::vector<Point> points;
};

struct Geometry
{
    std::string id;
    std::unique_ptr<Polyline> polyline;
};
```

Some utility functions

```
void printPolyline(const Polyline& polyline)
{
    size_t idx = 0;
    for (const auto& p : polyline.points)
    {
        cout << "point idx = " << idx << "\t point: "
             << p.x << ", " << p.y << ", " << p.z << endl;
        ++idx;
    }
}

void printGeometryDetails(const Geometry& geometry)
{
    cout << "id = " << geometry.id << endl;
    if (geometry.polyline == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Polyline is null" << endl;
        return;
    }
    printPolyline(*geometry.polyline);
}
```

Following is the way I am trying to run stuff.

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, const Geometry&> map;

    std::unique_ptr<Polyline> geometry = std::make_unique<Polyline>();
    geometry->points.emplace_back(0, 0, 0);
    geometry->points.emplace_back(1, 0, 0);
    geometry->points.emplace_back(2, 0, 0);

    map.insert({"geometry-id-1", {"id1", std::move(geometry)}});
    printGeometryDetails(map.find("geometry-id-1")->second);
}
```

I would expect the polyline to be printed but it shows "Polyline is null"(i.e, the condition `if (geometry.polyline == nullptr)` is evaluated to `true` in `printGeometryDetails` function) . I am really not sure what mistake I am doing here that is resulting in this behaviour.

I would really appreciate if anyone can pin point the mistake I am making.

System details: Linux Ubuntu 20.04, compiler details:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: you cannot have `const Geometry&` as mapped type in a map. Thats what `std::reference_wrapper` is for

Comment: why do you want reference in the first place? Why not `std::unordered_map<std::string, Geometry> map;`  ?

Comment: I was trying to replicate a bigger problem with this. The thing is `Geometry` has the copy constructor deleted. And this was the main reason why I wanted to hold reference in the map.

Comment: a reference is just a reference. Who keeps the actual object?

Comment: you don't need to copy when you use `emplace`

Comment: The data is loaded from disk. The data is part of flatbuffer schema which has the struct's copy constructors deleted.

Comment: As pointed out by others, the lifetime is the poblem.
Try adding prints to the ctor and dtor of `Polyline`, that could help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lifetime of the `Geometry` object created for insertion in the map, i.e. this line:

```
    map.insert({"geometry-id-1", {"id1", std::move(geometry)}});
```

The map stores only a reference to the object, but the object itself does not live after this line.

Replacing it with the following should make it work as you expected:

```
    Geometry g = {"id1", std::move(geometry)};
    map.insert({"geometry-id-1", g});
```